# Top navigation problem

Tags: navigation, hyperlink, top-navigation

My top navigation menu wont allow me to delete a link.

The link is above all others links, and points to my startpage. I have tried "edit links" and navigation settings, but the link dont show up their .

It looks like this:

Link1

Link2  Link3 Link4

Comment: What does the DOM-Explorer (F12) show? Has this "link above all others" been created within the "DeltaTopNavigation"? I suggest it was built out of this region and cannot been reached by the standard edit / delete methods.

Comment: Have you checked the Term Store Management page? Perhaps your navigation is pulling the links from here.  It is accessed via Site Settings.

Comment: I found this page that solved my problem. Guess its called "Home" link. http://bemusedbi.blogspot.com.es/2013/04/hiding-home-link-in-sharepoint-2013-top.html